# Natural sort an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, sorting

I need to sort an array of arrays given to me. The array looks something like this.

```
var provided_array = [
    inner_array_one = ['1', '10', '11', 'Alpha', '2A'],
    inner_array_two = ['Hotdogs', 'Pies', 'Burgers', 'Kebabs', 'Tacos']
    ];
```

I've kept this example as minimal as possible. In reality there are usually about a dozen of these inner arrays.

The data in inner_array_one is related to that of inner_array_two by index.
I.e. "2A" is related to "Tacos".

The sorting needs to be "natural" i.e. 2 before 10. 
The overall expected output I need is

```
provided_array[
    inner_array_one['1', '2A', '10', '11', 'Alpha'],
    inner_array_two['Hotdogs', 'Tacos', 'Pies', 'Burgers', 'Kebabs']
    ];
```

I've tried to use the javascript sort function but it seems it's only capable of sorting the order of the inner_arrays and not the content of those said arrays.

Is what I want achievable?

Comment: Please add what you've tried so far

Comment: Not with `provided_array.sort(…)`, no.

Comment: Anything is possible with enough time and resources... that being said, you could write a stand alone function that would achieve this.  We aren't going to write it for you, take a stab at it, see if you can figure it out. If you can't, post what you tried and we will be more than happy to help.

Comment: Why do you use [parallel arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array) in the first place? [Transpose them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) and then sort your array of objects.

Comment: @Bergi not my app and javascript is not my domain, trying to have as light a touch as possible with this. If I don't find a reasonable solution my plan was to rework the structure to something more reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a helper array for the indices and sort natural the first inner array and map all arrays with the indices array.

```js
var arrays = [
        ['1', '10', '11', 'Alpha', '2A'],
        ['Hotdogs', 'Pies', 'Burgers', 'Kebabs', 'Tacos']
    ],
    indices = Object.keys(arrays[0]);
    
indices.sort((a, b) => arrays[0][a].localeCompare(arrays[0][b], undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }));

console.log(arrays.map(a => indices.map(i => a[i])));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `indices = Array.from(arrays[0].keys())`

Comment: @Bergi, i know i've something forgotten. thanks. another way would be to use `Object.keys`.

Comment: `Object.keys` returns an array, all other collection `keys` methods return iterators

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`kn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) option of `.localeCompare()` for natural sorting of alphanumeric strings.

```
var provided_array = [
    inner_array_one = ['1', '10', '11', 'Alpha', '2A'],
    inner_array_two = ['Hotdogs', 'Pies', 'Burgers', 'Kebabs', 'Tacos']
    ];


provided_array.forEach(item => item.sort((obj1, obj2) => obj1.localeCompare(obj2, 'en-US-u-kn-true')));


console.log(provided_array);
```

### DEMO FIDDLE

Comment: Just keep that the localeCompare options might not always be available, at least in android webkit see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Answer (score 0):

This simple function would sort an array of arrays at any level of nesting:

```
function sortArray(arr) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr) || !arr.length) return;
    if (Array.isArray(arr[0]))
        arr.forEach(ele => sortArray(ele));
    arr = arr.sort();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For natural sort of numbers at least one can use:

```
const arr = [10, 100, 0, 2, 22, 3, 33, 1];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  const numA = a.toString();
  const numB = b.toString();
  const lenA = numA.length;
  const lenB = numB.length;

  if (lenA !== lenB) {
    return lenA - lenB;
  }
  
  return a - b;
});

console.log(arr); // Output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 22, 33, 100]
```